# Problem with large menu on mobile devices / tablets

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm working on a WordPress website for a client.
I have a (large) menu with many sub-menu items.

Problem: On mobile devices / tablets the scroll is locked for the main-menu and some sub-menu items are not visible when the top items are opened.

[image: Image showing the problem] - visible only 3 of 6 items

It is possible to somehow fix this? Any ideas?

I tried with the following code I got from [this website](https://medium.com/@ferie/detect-a-touch-device-with-only-css-9f8e30fa1134) (with scroll also with auto)*:

```
@media (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) 
{
  #primary-menu 
  {
    overflow-y: scroll !important; 
  }
}
```

---

[Link to my website](https://www.flexinstal.ro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give overflow css to #masthead

```
#masthead{
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: it's working, but revealed, the height of the menu is the height of the image when revealed. It is possible to make the height of the menu 90-100% when is revealed, just using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Using Omi's answer and after a few hours of struggling, I found a solution (but still testing):

```
/*This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px and also iPads specifically.*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), 
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  
{
   /*...*/
    .mean-container .mean-nav 
    {
        overflow-y: auto;
        max-height: 45vh; /*old value: 75vh*/
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```